# Removing duplicate values from structure key=data, value=count (mySQL/mariaDB)

Tags: mysql, json, indexing, duplicates, mariadb

I have table ID, JSON(key=date value=count)

| ID | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 123123 | {"2021-12-25": 1, "2021-12-26": 1, "2022-01-02": 0} |
| 34535345 | {"2021-11-28": 2200, "2021-12-06": 2200, "2021-12-28": 2200, "2022-01-02": 2200, "2022-01-04": 2200} |

I have 2 questions.

1.How can I take value as index JSON?

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(t1.column2, '$."2022-01-02"')=0;
```

This query is working, but I would use JSON_EXTRACT(t1.column2, '$[2]') as array index, because dates is arbitrary. Is it possible?

2. How can I delete key=value if there are duplicates value  (example:"2021-12-26": 1)?

Please help

Comment: *I would use JSON_EXTRACT(t1.column2, '$[2]') as array index* Impossible, the value is an object, not an array. In JSON object the ordering of the properties is not defined. *How can I delete key=value if there are duplicates value* Parse, DISTINCT, reconstruct.

Comment: Use, for example, array of objects. I.e. `[{"2021-11-28": 2200}, {"2021-12-06": 2200}, {"2021-12-28": 2200}, {"2022-01-02": 2200}, {"2022-01-04": 2200}]`. Or an array of objects with values as properties, like `[ ... {"ordinality":2, "date":"2021-12-06", "value":2200}, ... ]`. But the best way - parse and normalize your JSON to regular table.

Comment: Thank you! That is a pity ... that json not suitable for statistic. I will think about new structure. Any ideas?!

Comment: ) Thank you very mach, Akina. I will think!

Comment: Sorry @Akina, I don't understand "But the best way - parse and normalize your JSON to regular table." Delete second column current structure and add column as date? It will be very long table

Comment: Second option... many lines by one id. It will be very high table

Comment: Create a table `(id, ordinality, date, value)`. Save your data into it, one value per row. This is easy-to-process structure. And you can reconstruct your JSON easily when you need in it. PS. *It will be very high table* "Very high table" - above 1kkk rows?

Comment: 6 million id * variation date_value. It will be very high table